# Android Crouton library implementing Custom Views

Tags: android, crouton

Is it possible to completely change the Layout of a Crouton? I've seen a few of posts about changing the view which actually came down to just wanting to change the font but nothing about actually changing the layout.

I've already got croutons displaying nicely and been playing about with styles but couldn't quite find how to do what I want. Basically what I want is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgXgv.png), which dismisses the crouton when clicking the cross. So it's just a textview and a button!

I did see this within the Crouton Library but couldn't really see how to use it for my purpose.

```
public static Crouton make(Activity activity, View customView) {
return new Crouton(activity, customView);
}
```

Comment: Ok turns out it's much simpler than I first though... Just create a layout with all the views you want added to it into the make method, then call crouton.show();

Go [here](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton/blob/master/sample/src/de/keyboardsurfer/app/demo/crouton/CroutonFragment.java) for more details.

(Sorry couldn't add it as an answer because my rep is too low)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link you](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/useful-android-libraries-crouton/) may get answer

Another [Link](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton)

His idea is to show in-app notifications (not to be confused with Android’s persistent notifications) at a fixed place of the Activity to which the notification is relevant. This way the context of the notification is always correct